# Tsql add column using synonyms

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have to add two columns to a table

and I have a synonym associated with that table

For example:

> My table name is table_abc and the synonyms is table_1

When i try to add column to the table in normal way,

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1]
ADD test_1 varbinary(MAX),
test_2 varbinary(MAX);
```

Following error occurs :

> Cannot alter 'dbo.table_1' because it is not a table.

Is there a correct way using synonyms to add a column to the table? or is it just a wrong way to add a column?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter table with alias name and you have to add column to the table
in this way

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_abc]
    ADD test_1 varbinary(MAX)
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_abc]

ADD test_2 varbinary(MAX)
```

Comment: But is it possible to use alias name to alter table? Since i have to alter tables from different server and the table name varies with the server but with same synonym

Comment: @ProgrammingBaKa it is not possible to alter table with alias name

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe i will try to get the original table name from the synonym and use dynamic sql >___>

Comment: U can alter table from different databases in same server @ProgrammingBaKa

Comment: but the problem is that i don't know the actual name of the tables in the server but only the synonym of the table

Answer (score 1):

**We cannot alter Synonyms created on table in Sql Server.**

We can only do

```
CREATE SYNONYM (Transact-SQL)
DROP SYNONYM (Transact-SQL)
```

**If we want to alter main table**

```
alter table table_abc
add test_1 varbinary(MAX),
test_2 varbinary(MAX);
```

**To get the table name from the synonym name **

```
SELECT  base_object_name,* FROM  sys.synonyms where name like'%Synonym name%'
```